# JENKINS build fatal error: file has been modified since the precompiled header was built

Tags: xcode, macos, jenkins

Hello IOS build in Jenkins failed with:

```
 20:30:25 fatal error: file '/Users/epa/workspace/LIB-   continious/Pods/Headers/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h' has been modified since the precompiled header   '/Users/epa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Horizon-   byelvvypwyklmtfohzjdakhwxgnk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Horizon-Prefix-  dhhovaqluqdqbgeholxnfujpmhmg/Horizon-Prefix.pch.pch' was built
```

I have got only ssh connect